# How to make the structures generated by dput() more amenable to the character length restrictions of stackoverflow

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm trying to submit questions to stack overflow, but some of the dataframes I need for my examples are large and made larger by dput(). Is there a workaround to this? For example, here is a structure generated by dput():

```
d<-structure(list(ID = 20L, QnSinV1 = 0L, QnSinV2 = 0L, QnSinV3 = 0L, 
QnSize = -0.007564124, QnWt = 14.4, QnWtLsCL = 0.486111111, 
ClaustPer = 0L, QnSurvCL = 1L, ColWtCL = 9.9, ColWtCL_6 = 53.7, 
ColGrowthCL_6 = 5.424242424, QnSurvCL_6 = 1L, IR = 0.0332632, 
SH = 1.0264, HL = 0.4638, MLH = structure(182L, .Label = c("0.21052631578947367", 
"0.23157894736842105", "0.2602739726027397", "0.2857142857142857", 
"0.29310344827586204", "0.29545454545454547", "0.2962962962962963", 
"0.2978723404255319", "0.29850746268656714", "0.3", "0.3048780487804878", 
"0.30612244897959184", "0.3076923076923077", "0.30927835051546393", 
"0.3106796116504854", "0.3125", "0.31958762886597936", "0.3235294117647059", 
"0.3246753246753247", "0.3269230769230769", "0.3333333333333333", 
"0.33653846153846156", "0.336734693877551", "0.3380281690140845", 
"0.34065934065934067", "0.3434343434343434", "0.34408602150537637", 
"0.34615384615384615", "0.34782608695652173", "0.34831460674157305", 
"0.35294117647058826", "0.35443037974683544", "0.3548387096774194", 
"0.35555555555555557", "0.3557692307692308", "0.35789473684210527", 
"0.358695652173913", "0.36082474226804123", "0.36363636363636365", 
"0.36585365853658536", "0.36633663366336633", "0.36666666666666664", 
"0.3673469387755102", "0.3684210526315789", "0.36893203883495146", 
"0.3695652173913043", "0.3711340206185567", "0.37254901960784315", 
"0.37362637362637363", "0.37373737373737376", "0.375", "0.3763440860215054", 
"0.3764705882352941", "0.37755102040816324", "0.37777777777777777", 
"0.3786407766990291", "0.3793103448275862", "0.38", "0.38144329896907214", 
"0.38202247191011235", "0.38235294117647056", "0.38372093023255816", 
"0.3838383838383838", "0.38461538461538464", "0.3854166666666667", 
"0.38613861386138615", "0.3870967741935484", "0.3877551020408163", 
"0.3883495145631068", "0.3894736842105263", "0.38961038961038963", 
"0.39", "0.391304347826087", "0.3917525773195876", "0.39215686274509803", 
"0.3939393939393939", "0.3942307692307692", "0.3950617283950617", 
"0.3953488372093023", "0.3958333333333333", "0.39603960396039606", 
"0.3978494623655914", "0.3979591836734694", "0.39805825242718446", 
"0.4", "0.4019607843137255", "0.4020618556701031", "0.40217391304347827", 
"0.4024390243902439", "0.40384615384615385", "0.40404040404040403", 
"0.4050632911392405", "0.40594059405940597", "0.40625", "0.4065934065934066", 
"0.4069767441860465", "0.4077669902912621", "0.40789473684210525", 
"0.40816326530612246", "0.40860215053763443", "0.41", "0.4105263157894737", 
"0.410958904109589", "0.4111111111111111", "0.4117647058823529", 
"0.41237113402061853", "0.4125", "0.41304347826086957", "0.41379310344827586", 
"0.41414141414141414", "0.4146341463414634", "0.4158415841584158", 
"0.4166666666666667", "0.4174757281553398", "0.4175824175824176", 
"0.41836734693877553", "0.41935483870967744", "0.42", "0.4215686274509804", 
"0.42168674698795183", "0.4222222222222222", "0.422680412371134", 
"0.4230769230769231", "0.4235294117647059", "0.42424242424242425", 
"0.42528735632183906", "0.425531914893617", "0.42574257425742573", 
"0.42696629213483145", "0.4270833333333333", "0.42718446601941745", 
"0.42857142857142855", "0.43", "0.43010752688172044", "0.43023255813953487", 
"0.43137254901960786", "0.43157894736842106", "0.4326923076923077", 
"0.4329896907216495", "0.4342105263157895", "0.43434343434343436", 
"0.43478260869565216", "0.43564356435643564", "0.43617021276595747", 
"0.43636363636363634", "0.4368932038834951", "0.4375", "0.4383561643835616", 
"0.4387755102040816", "0.43902439024390244", "0.43956043956043955", 
"0.44", "0.44047619047619047", "0.44086021505376344", "0.4411764705882353", 
"0.4421052631578947", "0.4423076923076923", "0.4431818181818182", 
"0.44329896907216493", "0.4444444444444444", "0.44554455445544555", 
"0.44565217391304346", "0.44660194174757284", "0.44680851063829785", 
"0.44776119402985076", "0.4479166666666667", "0.4482758620689655", 
"0.449438202247191", "0.45", "0.45054945054945056", "0.45098039215686275", 
"0.45161290322580644", "0.4519230769230769", "0.45263157894736844", 
"0.45348837209302323", "0.4536082474226804", "0.45454545454545453", 
"0.45544554455445546", "0.45555555555555555", "0.4563106796116505", 
"0.45652173913043476", "0.4574468085106383", "0.4583333333333333", 
"0.4588235294117647", "0.45918367346938777", "0.45977011494252873", 
"0.46", "0.4606741573033708", "0.46078431372549017", "0.46153846153846156", 
"0.46296296296296297", "0.4631578947368421", "0.4634146341463415", 
"0.4639175257731959", "0.46464646464646464", "0.46511627906976744", 
"0.46534653465346537", "0.46601941747572817", "0.46808510638297873", 
"0.46875", "0.46938775510204084", "0.46987951807228917", 
"0.47", "0.47058823529411764", "0.47191011235955055", "0.47368421052631576", 
"0.4742268041237113", "0.47474747474747475", "0.4752475247524752", 
"0.47572815533980584", "0.4787234042553192", "0.4791666666666667", 
"0.47959183673469385", "0.48", "0.4803921568627451", "0.4807692307692308", 
"0.48314606741573035", "0.4838709677419355", "0.48484848484848486", 
"0.48514851485148514", "0.4854368932038835", "0.4864864864864865", 
"0.48863636363636365", "0.4895833333333333", "0.4897959183673469", 
"0.49", "0.49019607843137253", "0.49038461538461536", "0.4939759036144578", 
"0.4942528735632184", "0.4946236559139785", "0.49473684210526314", 
"0.494949494949495", "0.49504950495049505", "0.49514563106796117", 
"0.5", "0.5048543689320388", "0.5050505050505051", "0.5051546391752577", 
"0.5053763440860215", "0.5057471264367817", "0.5064935064935064", 
"0.5096153846153846", "0.5098039215686274", "0.51", "0.5102040816326531", 
"0.5104166666666666", "0.5145631067961165", "0.5151515151515151", 
"0.5154639175257731", "0.5176470588235295", "0.5180722891566265", 
"0.5192307692307693", "0.5196078431372549", "0.52", "0.5204081632653061", 
"0.5222222222222223", "0.5242718446601942", "0.524390243902439", 
"0.5247524752475248", "0.5252525252525253", "0.5263157894736842", 
"0.5288461538461539", "0.5294117647058824", "0.53125", "0.5319148936170213", 
"0.5339805825242718", "0.5340909090909091", "0.5353535353535354", 
"0.5384615384615384", "0.54", "0.5408163265306123", "0.5416666666666666", 
"0.5445544554455446", "0.5533980582524272", "0.5543478260869565", 
"0.5631067961165048", "0.5643564356435643", "0.5652173913043478", 
"0.5673076923076923", "0.5714285714285714", "0.5742574257425742"
), class = "factor"), Aat2 = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.21863117870722434", "1"), class = "factor"), Acon5 = 0, 
Acy1 = 0, Anna = 0.562376237623762, Baez = 0, Baron_harkonnen = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.09421841541755889", "1"), class = "factor"), Beatles = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.015296367112810707", "1"), class = "factor"), Bertha = 1, 
Black_Crow = 0, Blackbird = 0, Blue_Jay = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.40943396226415096", "1"), class = "factor"), C1 = 0, C147 = 0, 
C204 = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", "0.47195357833655704", 
"1"), class = "factor"), C21 = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.32514177693761814", "1"), class = "factor"), C216_pigtail = 1, 
C234 = 1, C259 = 1, C278_PT = 0, C294 = 0, C316 = 1, C334 = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.19805825242718447", "1"), class = "factor"), C367 = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.27766990291262134", "1"), class = "factor"), C368_PigTail = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.35236220472440943", "1"), class = "factor"), C485 = 0, 
C487_PigTail = 0.424311926605505, C536 = 1, Cactus_tree = 0, 
Carey = 1, Carnival = 0, Cool_water = structure(2L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.25961538461538464", "1"), class = "factor"), Coyote = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.36926147704590817", "1"), class = "factor"), Darwi_Odrade = 0, 
Daytripper = 1, Deadpool = structure(2L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.13246753246753246", "1"), class = "factor"), Diamond_Joe = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.26411290322580644", "1"), class = "factor"), Emma_Frost = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.34959349593495936", "1"), class = "factor"), G3pdh1 = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.47514910536779326", "1"), class = "factor"), Glass_onion_v2 = 0, 
Handy_dandy = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", "0.38381742738589214", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Harvest = 1, Heartland = 0, i_109 = 1, 
i_113 = 1, i_114 = 1, i_120_PigTail = 1, i_126 = 1, i_127 = 0, 
i_132 = 0, i_135 = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", "0.39122137404580154", 
"1"), class = "factor"), i129 = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.29770992366412213", "1"), class = "factor"), Imagine = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.054820415879017016", "1"), class = "factor"), Jackstraw_PigTail = 1, 
Jam_session = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", "0.43259557344064387", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Jericho = 1, Jerry_Garcia = 1, Jokerman = 1, 
Jude = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", "0.33397312859884837", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Julia = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.36472945891783565", "1"), class = "factor"), Kitty_Pryde = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.39096267190569745", "1"), class = "factor"), Maggie_mae = 0, 
Majesty = structure(2L, .Label = c("0", "0.42398286937901497", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Miles_teg = 0, Million_miles = 0.523917995444191, 
Monkey = 0, Mozambique = 0.504385964912281, Neil_Young = 0, 
Nettie_Moore = 1, Pam = 1, Percy = 1, Pgm1 = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.23495145631067962", "1"), class = "factor"), Piggies = 0, 
Psylocke = 0, Queen_jane = structure(3L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.34518828451882844", "1"), class = "factor"), Ramble = 0, 
red_ant = 1, Sam_Stonev2 = 0, Seastones = 0, Sinv_25 = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.30210325047801145", "1"), class = "factor"), Sinv12 = 0, 
Siona = 0, Sol_11 = 1, Sol_18 = 1, Sol_20 = 0, Sol_42f = 1, 
Sol_49 = 0.74949083503055, Sol_6 = 0, Sol_J1 = 0, Sol_M2 = 1, 
Sol_M3 = 1, Starr = 0, st_stephen = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.059670781893004114", "1"), class = "factor"), Sun_King = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.15346534653465346", "1"), class = "factor"), sunrise = 1, 
Sway = 0, Taxman = 1, Tombstone_blues = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.35528942115768464", "1"), class = "factor"), Trouble = 0, 
Tweedy = structure(2L, .Label = c("0", "0.45154185022026433", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Walrus = 0, Weight = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.17805383022774326", "1"), class = "factor"), Wigwam = structure(2L, .Label = c("0", 
"0.26756756756756755", "1"), class = "factor"), Workingman_Blues = 1, 
Yellow_submarine = 0), .Names = c("ID", "QnSinV1", "QnSinV2", "QnSinV3", "QnSize", "QnWt", "QnWtLsCL", "ClaustPer", "QnSurvCL", "ColWtCL", "ColWtCL_6", "ColGrowthCL_6", "QnSurvCL_6", "IR", "SH", "HL", "MLH", "Aat2", "Acon5", "Acy1", "Anna", "Baez", "Baron_harkonnen", "Beatles", "Bertha", "Black_Crow", "Blackbird", "Blue_Jay", "C1", "C147", "C204", "C21", "C216_pigtail", "C234", "C259", "C278_PT", "C294", "C316", "C334", "C367", "C368_PigTail", "C485", "C487_PigTail", "C536", "Cactus_tree", "Carey", "Carnival", "Cool_water", "Coyote","Darwi_Odrade", "Daytripper", "Deadpool", "Diamond_Joe", "Emma_Frost", "G3pdh1", "Glass_onion_v2", "Handy_dandy", "Harvest", "Heartland", "i_109", "i_113", "i_114", "i_120_PigTail", "i_126", "i_127", "i_132", "i_135", "i129", "Imagine", "Jackstraw_PigTail", "Jam_session", "Jericho", "Jerry_Garcia", "Jokerman", "Jude", "Julia", "Kitty_Pryde", "Maggie_mae", "Majesty", "Miles_teg", "Million_miles", "Monkey", "Mozambique", "Neil_Young", "Nettie_Moore", "Pam", "Percy", "Pgm1", "Piggies", "Psylocke", "Queen_jane", "Ramble", "red_ant", "Sam_Stonev2", "Seastones", "Sinv_25", "Sinv12", "Siona", "Sol_11", "Sol_18", "Sol_20", "Sol_42f", "Sol_49", "Sol_6", "Sol_J1", "Sol_M2", "Sol_M3", "Starr", "st_stephen", "Sun_King", "sunrise", "Sway", "Taxman", "Tombstone_blues", "Trouble", "Tweedy", "Walrus", "Weight", "Wigwam", "Workingman_Blues", "Yellow_submarine"), row.names = 14L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I doubt posting this information in whole is finally helpful. If you want to reproduce a bigger scenario, sketch out the basics in the question, and post a link to e.g. an online compiler example.

Comment: I have encountered an example today where the error I'm trying to ask for help about is replaced by a different error entirely when I create a small, say 20-row, subset of my dataset. This hardly warrants a downvote; it's a valid question.

Comment: Not familiar with R; is there a prettyprint that'd format that to look less... uh, awful?

Comment: It's my unfamiliarity with the nuances of R that is generating my errors in the first place (hence going to stack overflow). I know exactly what I want to do in the abstract, but I don't know how to get R to do it. I can't make my error reproducible with a small dataset.

Comment: Perhaps you should figure out what's causing the error on the small dataset *first*. Tracking that down could give you a better understanding of fundamentals that you may be missing now. If you can't even get a small dataset to work, it suggests that there may be something wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 11):

The visual appearance of the results of `dput()` is not going to be improved upon. We generally *recommend* it's use for providing example data because it is the most reliable way to specify an R object that can simply be copy+pasted into an R session and it will exactly represent the data structure the asker is dealing with.

This is crucial for R questions because many issues revolve around the precise structure of the asker's data, and they (understandably) tend to be **quite** unreliable when describing their data in words. A tabular display in the question of a small bit of data is sometimes ok, if the problem is small and simple. But usually it's better to use `dput()`.

I'm going to agree with Shog9's general recommendation, though, which may not be entirely satisfying. The only circumstances in which an R question should *require* example data where `dput()` is unwieldy should be performance related. As in, you're trying to do something at scale and you need help coming up with a solution that's just plain faster. In those cases, it should almost always be possible to provide 4-5 lines of simple code that *generate* a very large data set for people to test on.

Otherwise, if you really, truly can only reproduce your problem with *all* 121 columns of that data frame, then I'd agree with Shog that you might not be ready to ask a question yet. You probably need to spend some more time debugging and trying to find a smaller example that illustrates your problem.

A potential compromise would be to put the `dput()` output in a gist, or some other off site location and link to it. Opinions vary on that; many people aren't bothered by it, but some folks on SO feel more strongly that questions should be completely self-contained. Strictly within the R tag community, it is generally tolerated. However, you should also be aware that while it may be tolerated, many folks may read your question and simply not want to put in the time to go fetch your enormous data set. So there's a small tradeoff here in possibly scaring off some knowledgable folks from answering. (I've actually seen people linking to >200MB files and saying that that is their "example data". Not cool.)

(And finally, I can't help but comment on the fact that the example data in this question immediately sets of alarm bells since you have numeric data encoded as factors. That is almost never what you really want. Apologies if that is old news to you...)

Comment: It's a little bit of a compromise, but can't `dput(droplevels(d))` also be an improvement (if all factor levels are not required)?

Comment: @AnandaMahto As long as they test that the problem persists under that limitation, sure, that would surely help if there are tons of levels.

Comment: Usually just `dput(head(d, n))` solves the problem

Answer (score 6):

First off, if R has a [prettyprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint) function or utility, get it and use it.

Beyond that, do what you can to reproduce the problem / formulate the question with as small a dataset as possible. It may take some trial and error to determine what size that is, but this isn't necessarily time wasted - include this information in your question as well, as it may prove useful to those attempting to determine the source of your problem.